# Zend_Form advanced usage(Array)

Tags: php, forms, zend-form, zend-form-element

I'm quite busy with working with the Zend_Form object.

I'm building a form which will be used to create new invoices.
[image: Form which should be build with Zend_Form]

As you can see in the above image it's a form with several different input fields on  different places on the page and in the HTML code.

Normally you would use decorators to do this but I don't think this is a preferrable situation.

The button which inserts new HTML creates new input fields with the same names but with [NUMBER] at the end(creates arrays).

I think it's the best to just add the fields manually in the view script(Pseudo code: echo Zend_Form_Text_Element->toHtml();..

Can anyone give me advice how to get this to work properly?

Comment: Are you asking whether your approach is good or do you need some specific tips? As for the first, I've done this more or less the same way and it's quite a mess but it works ;) As for the second, replace `toHtml` with `render()` or `renderViewHelper()` and you're good to go ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the view script decorator. Here is a good [link](http://devzone.zend.com/1240/decorators-with-zend_form/).

Scroll down to the part where it says: **Example: Full Customization Using the ViewScript Decorator**

Here is a sample form built using the view script:

```
<h4>Please register with us!</h4>
<form action="<?= $this->escape($this->form->getAction() ?>"
      method="<?= $this->escape($this->form->getMethod() ?>">

<fieldset>
    <legend>Demographics</legend>
    <p>
        Please provide us the following information so we can know more about
        you.
    </p>

    <?= $this->form->age ?>
    <?= $this->form->nationality ?>
    <?= $this->form->income ?>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>User Information</legend>
    <p>
        Now please tell us who you are and how to contact you.
    </p>

    <?= $this->form->firstname ?>
    <?= $this->form->lastname ?>
    <?= $this->form->email ?>
    <?= $this->form->address1 ?>
    <?= $this->form->address2 ?>
    <?= $this->form->city ?>
    <?= $this->form->state ?>
    <?= $this->form->postal ?>
    <?= $this->form->phone ?>
</fieldset>

<?= $this->form->submit ?>
</form>
```

This way u can have full control over the html of the form and u won't need to suffer from the decorators hell :D

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the answer, I'll starting working it out right now and let you know if this worked for me.

Comment: @E.Clark glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solves ur problem ;)